# COM+ Interop UnmanagedType Struct

Tags: .net, struct, com, interop, com+

After running TlbImp on a COM+ DLL, and getting the interoperable DLL, I got some methods like this:

```
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)]
    public virtual extern object ListContacts([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)] [In] [Out] ref object ContactTypeID, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)] [In] [Out] ref object LastName, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)] [In] [Out] ref object FirstName, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)] [In] [Out] ref object City);
```

In this example, param and return types are all "UnmanagedType.Struct".

How can I determine their equivalent .NET types in order to pass the right params, and read the returned values?

Comment: It is a pretty clunky method, the arguments and return type are *variants*.  Not uncommon for a COM server that was designed to be used in a scripting language.  A variant is a "could be any type" variable type, that's why you get *object*.  But in practice only certain types will work.  You can guess that LastName and City are a string and ContactTypeId is probably an enum.   And you probably get an object back.  You need the programming manual to be sure, contact the owner or author of the component if you don't have one.

Comment: Thank you Hans, for the detailed explanation of each variable and the suggestion.